# ¿Cómo validar que el registro no exista en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Hago una consulta en MySQL con un campo `id_cliente`, y necesito comparar que si el `id_cliente` existe en db no haga nada y si no existe la guarde el `id_cliente` en base de datos.

Lo que sucede es que el valor del `id_cliente` es de tipo `varchar` y no, yo no asigno los `id_cliente`, es respuesta de paypal, el ingreso de los datos lo hace correctamente pero no verifica si existe, solo ingresa los datos.

Dejo código para ver si me pueden decir en que estoy mal.

```
$id_cliente_paypal= $_POST['payer_id'];

$check = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = '".$id_cliente_paypal."'");

if($check == $id_cliente_paypal){
    exit();
}else{
    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO clientes )
    //no puse todo el codigo de insersion
}
```

Comment: mysqli_query te devuelve un array si la consulta se ha ejecutado (otra cosa es que te devuelva resultados), y un false si hay error. Un array es distinto de un id, por lo que se ejecuta siempre el ELSE de tu condicion. Revisa que te devuelve `$check` y ajusta tu codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes evaluar de esta manera:

```
  if (mysqli_num_rows($check) == 0) {//Si no encuentra resultados, que inserte a la BD
   mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO clientes... )
  }
```

Comment: Hola te lo agradezco mucho, funciona a la perfeccion